# How to retrive value from array of arrays?

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

```
[["sports","Any"],["sports","cricket"],["sports","football"],["sports","other"]]
```

If I want to retrieve `cricket` from that?
How to achieve it?

Comment: you better try googling "two dimensional arrays" in the language you want to implement this

Comment: I already did that but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the language, but I expect `[1][1]` should do it.

assuming your array is called `arr` then `arr[1]` refers to `["sports","cricket"]` (0 based index) which is itself an array, so you can indentify elements the same way as usual... using `[1]` to access `"cricket"`... so all together: `arr[1][1]`.

Comment: I am doing it in JQuery

Comment: @VaibhaVWakharkaR you need to show more code surrounding the data. What is the variable name you are accessing?

Comment: `arr` is used as a placeholder for the name of the variable that holds your data.

Answer (score 0):

It is multidimensional array. I think you could use (don't know exactly because you didn't stated language).

```
array[1][1]
```

`array[1]` returns `["sports","cricket"]` which is array too, so we are adding `[1]` again to get `"cricket"`

Comment: I am doing it in JQuery

Comment: @VaibhaVWakharkaR So it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Depend from the language. For example:

**JAVA**:

```
String str = array[1][1];
```

**ObjectiveC**:

```
NSString *str = ((NSArray *)array[1])[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you access the first array's element then the second array's element so:

```
arrayname[1][1]
```

would give you cricket back